# How can I put an array into an exponential

Tags: python, arrays, gaussian, exponential

I am trying to fit some data to a gaussian function. I am trying to do this using the optomize.curve_fit function. I cannot place my data into the math.exp(). How can I get around this?

```
def func(xdata, a,b, c):
    return a*math.exp(-((xdata-b)**2)/2*c**2)

plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'ro', label="original data")

popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata, maxfev=1000000)
plt.plot(xdata, func(xdata, *popt), label="Fitted Curve")
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Comment: If your data is a numpy array, use [`np.exp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.exp.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is how:

```
result = np.zeros(len(xdata))

def func(xdata, a,b, c):
    for x in range(len(xdata)):
        result[x] = a*math.exp(-((x-b)**2)/2*c**2)
    return result
plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'ro', label="original data")

popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata, maxfev=1000000)
plt.plot(xdata, func(xdata, *popt), label="Fitted Curve")
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np

def func(xdata, a, b, c):
    return a * np.exp(-((xdata-b)**2)/2*c**2)
```

if your data is not an numpy array try 
`xdata = np.array(xdata)`